# How to increase performance of Acer Aspire One 751h netbook?

Tags: windows-xp, performance

I have bought my new netbook Acer Aspire One 751h some days ago and was very unpleased with it performance - videotalking in skype is almost unuseable, watching videos on YouTube(even in standart definition) is like watching slideshow and all netbook have increadible lags if I'm running more then 4-5 programms in one time. **So, can somebody tell me how to impruve the performance of the netbook(OS - WinXP SP3)? And can you say me where to control power managment, please? Thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

As this has a slower processor and you are running multiple apps, it will likley perform poorly. Do you have 1 or 2 GB of RAM.  Try the Skype or Youtube with no other apps running.  Any better?  Do you have an AV scanner set do do agressive scans? Power management is usually in Control Panel under Power.

Answer (score 0):

I own one of these myself.

I have upgraded to 2gb ram and added and SD card to use for ReadyBoost with Windows 7.

I upgraded to Windows 7 from the Windows XP.

Be sure to get the latest drivers - particularly the video driver - to ensure the best performance.

Power Management can be reached by right clicking the battery icon (Vista and Windows 7 - not sure about xp since it has been so long since I used it).

Comment: FYI Power Management is within Control Panel, and a right-click away on the battery/AC power icon in XP

Answer (score 0):

Along with what the others said, check out Task Manager or that Performance Log thing built into Windows. Find out if you are CPU, RAM, or HDD-speed bound. From there hunt out the bad applications (hint: even netbooks get loads of bloatware installed on them from the manufacturer that are not needed)

Also, you were saying this about Skype and Youtube. Not be be obvious, but your internet is fast enough right?